# Prove that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, cardinals

> Prove: $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ is uncountable

Here is an excerpt from a proof of this result that I am struggling to follow:

[image]

As a part of the proof that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ is uncountable, my textbook defines the set $\bar{{Z}}$ as can be seen in the picture above. What I am confused about, is why we can presume that  $\bar{{Z}}$ is not equal to the empty set?

Comment: There isn't such a guarantee, but that is just fine.  Regardless of if $\overline{Z}$ is empty or not we would have $\overline{Z}$ is still not in the collection of $Z_n$ despite the fact that it should be since $\overline{Z}$ is indeed a subset of $\Bbb Z$.  Remember, the empty set is a subset of any other set, and as such should be an element of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ for any $X$.

Comment: Does $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ mean the set $\{0,1,2,...,n - 1\}$, then wouldn't $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ be empty anyways. Not that it matters at all.

Comment: But my problem is, if it is the empty set, we can add it to the list, and now the list should be complete. I don't see how $\bar{\mathbb{Z}}$ will appear again ad inifnitum after being added to the list.

Comment: Also I believe $Z_{n}$ is the nth element of the list of all subsets of Z, not the set {0,1,2,...,−1}.

Comment: @Shagester "*we can add it to the list, and now the list should be complete*"  but the assumption was that the list was *already* complete and didn't need anything added to it.  We showed that no attempt at having a complete list could have successfully had everything in the list, ergo no complete list could exist in the first place.

Comment: There is no reason to believe that 'the list will be complete' after adding $\bar{Z}$. For instance, if the original list is $Z_k = \{k\}$, then $\bar{Z}$ is the empty set. But adding that to the list clearly doesn't make the list contain all subsets (it's missing all the sets with more than 1 element). And this of course goes for _every_ list.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that $\bar{Z}$ may be empty, but this has no impact on the proof. Regardless of what $\bar{Z}$ is, it is still the case that $\bar{Z}$ is not in the collection of $Z_n$. Since we assumed that the list $Z_n$ was complete, this shows that such a list cannot exist. It will always be missing some subsets - which is precisely the argument being made.

---

Another way to see this is by finding the cardinality explicitly.

> **Claim:** The cardinality of $\mathcal P (\mathbb Z^+)$ is $2^{\aleph _0}$

There are a few different ways to prove the claim. I will get you started on two different approaches:

($1$) The first way is to find an upper and lower bound on the cardinality of $2^{\aleph _0}$ and then apply the Cantor Schroder Bernstein Theorem in order to conclude that the cardinality of $\mathcal P ( \mathbb Z ^+ ) = 2^{\aleph _0}$

We first look for an upper bound: $$ |\mathcal P(\mathbb Z^+) | \leq | \mathcal P( \mathbb Z)| = |2^{\mathbb Z}| = |2|^{|\mathbb Z|} = 2^{\aleph _0}$$ I will leave it to you to find a suitable lower bound in order to apply the Cantor Schroder Bernstein Theorem (note that we need the lower bound to be a set of cardinality $2^{\aleph _0}$).

($2$)  Alternatively, a second approach requires you to use the following lemma:

- **Lemma:** given any bijection $f : X \to Y$, there exists a bijection $g : 2^X \to 2^Y$ where $g(A) = \{f(x)\ |\ x \in A\}$

If you are able to use this result, then the proof is much more direct. We simply need to establish a bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Z^+$ in order to conclude that their power sets also biject each other. And once you have shown that the power sets biject each other, then this immediately proves the result since $2^{\aleph _0}$ is the cardinality of the power set of the natural numbers (by definition).

Again, I will leave the remainder of this proof to you.

---

Explicitly, the above proof may only seem to show that the cardinality of $\mathcal P (\mathbb Z^+)$ is $2^{\aleph _0}$. However, this also shows that $P( \mathbb Z^+)$ is uncountable since we have established a bijection with $\mathcal P (\mathbb{N})$ which is an uncountable set. And any set that bijects an uncountable set is itself uncountable (as required).

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question. If not, I'm happy to clarify anything that's unclear @Shagester